# MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER is not initialized at @angular/material-moment-adapter/index.ts

Tags: angular-material, momentjs

I am working on Node.js version 12.13, angular version 11.2.12,

I am trying to work with MatDatePicker. I have installed Moment.js dependency too.

While trying to use MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS under providers I am getting this compile time error.

*only initialized variables and constants can be referenced in decorators because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler in 'MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS'
MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER is not initialized at @angular/material-moment-adapter/index.ts *

Reinstalled npm. No luck.

Comment: can you share the module code